# Can I submit a predefined local variable as a POST w/out putting into a form field?

Tags: php, post, global-variables

I have a local variable I'd like to be sent along with the rest of the POST data taken from an HTML form. Is there a function that lets me put more data from the current page into the POST array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no function, simply add a hidden field with the value.

```
<input type='hidden' name='what_ever' value='<?php echo $my_var?>' />
```

If you need the value to remain totally hidden from the user, then use the SESSION to pass it's value between requests.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that when you say "local data" you mean client side data. You could do this with some javascript.

```
function addFormData(key, name) {
var f = document.getElementById('myform');
var g = document.createElement('input');
g.setAttribute('name', key);
g.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
g.value = name;
f.appendChild(g);
f.submit();
}
```